# Allocation of space for nvarchar and varchar

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I remember from some time ago being told in academia that Oracle would when given a varchar of (9) would allocate space to actually store 16 bytes worth of characters even though it only needed 9.  (pre-wide characters)

Is this still a thing(was this ever a thing)?  If I allocate nvarchar(63) will it maximize the storage space(assuming null character)?  Will it still take the same space as nvarchar(50)?  Is there any benefits to indexing?

I am primarily concerned with MSSQL, but would be interested to know of any databases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SQL Server allocates two bytes for very actual character in a nvarchar string. So for a nvarchar string declared as Nvarchar(10) ='Ben' Sql server will allow names of up to 10 characters and use six bytes to save the string 'Ben.' It will also use some space to save the actual length of the string (I believe two bytes).

Answer (score 6):

It does not preallocate space to nvarchar

the space is number of chars * 2 byte + 2 byte for size

if you stored 40 chars both  nvarchar(63) and  nvarchar(50) would be the same size  82 bytes

the difference is you cannot put 51 chars in nvarchar(50)

Comment: Far more succinctly put, SQL (as well as MySQL) does not pre-allocate space for VARCHAR cols, which is what I was looking for. Thank you.